# Authlogic: generates "Email has already been taken" error twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

I'm using authlogic with my user model, with the login field set to use email, thus:

```
acts_as_authentic do |c| 
  c.login_field = :email 
end
```

If i try to make a new user, and the email is already in use, it adds a duplicate email error twice: (from the console)

```
user = User.new(:first_name => "fred", :last_name => "Smith", :email => User.last.email);user.valid?;errors = user.errors
=> {:email=>["has already been taken", "has already been taken"]}
```

I'm guessing this is something to do with using the email as the login, maybe?  I don't have any other validations on email apart from validates_format_of, and i experimented with removing that validation (doesn't make any difference).

It's a pain as it's messing up my the errors i show on the form when validation fails.

Before i go trying to hack authlogic, does anyone know why this might be happening?  thanks, max

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue. Try calling `config.validate_email_field = false` in the `acts_as_authentic` block. It'll still validate the login field, which in our case in the email field, but only once.

```
acts_as_authentic do |config|
  config.login_field :email
  config.validate_email_field = false
    ...
end
```

Comment: Also make sure you dont have validation manually assigned on that field, ie. `validates :email, :presence => true`. This resulted for me in having the message returned 3 times.

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods in Authlogic: validate_email_field and validate_login_field.

These methods disable/enable the specific validations:

- validate_email_field: https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/master/lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic/email.rb#L101-L103
- validate_login_field: https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/master/lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic/login.rb#L132-L134

I also use `config.login_field :email` in my app, and I need to be sure that `User#email` is validated. So in my case I chose to use `config.validate_login_field = false` because of the difference between the validations.